# Firefox console showing syntax issue in javascript code

Tags: javascript

When I type this line in Firefox/Chrome console it is showing Syntax error:

```js
var arr = {
  Accept: "*/*",
  ​"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
 ​ "Accept-Language": "en-IN",
 ​ Connection: "Keep-Alive",
 ​ Host: "google.com"
};
```

I can see no problem here. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unicode \u200b in front of each line.

[image]

Here's a fixed version

```
var arr = {
  Accept: "*/*",
  ​"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
 ​ "Accept-Language": "en-IN",
 ​ Connection: "Keep-Alive",
 ​ Host: "google.com"
};
```

Comment: i'm not able to remove using backslash etc. How to remove? I'm on Windows10

Comment: Put your cursor just after each comma, hold shift, press left arrow until you get to the " and then delete? Sorry I don't have a better answer

Answer (score 0):

There are weird invisible characters in there.

[image]